# cython: how to specifiy the directory rather than --inplace?

Tags: cython

I want to package my python module to c using cython.

It work using the following command:

```
python setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

The `--inplace` option creates the shared object file in the current directory. However, I want the  shared object files are created in a specified file. How can I implement this function?